# How to start another SignalR connection based on another one

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using a javascript web app which was connecting through SignalR to aspnet core service A, residing in a docker container. I have to add another service B as a middle between the 2. My guess was that I should split the SignalR connection in 2: first between javascript web app and service B, and second between service B and service A.
So far SignalR works between javascript web app and service B. While service B message arrives at service A, service A answer doesn't receive response from service B (for negotiation of the transport).

In service B I get 404 error, and in service A I see ws-connection time out.

This is what I did in service B:

```
targetUrl = serviceA_signalR_Url + javascript_app_request_query_string
_connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(targetUrl, options => {
    {
         options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
    })
    .Build();
_connection.StartAsync.Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily it was my fault. I was trying to use id parameter in the query string. It worked once I removed it